# Helpers are singleton classes?

Tags: helper, singleton

Given this code

```
<?php
class Vendor_Module_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

    protected $_currentCustomer = null;
    protected $_settingsHelper = null;

    public function involveCustomer($customer)
    {
        $this->_currentCustomer = $customer;
    }

    public function getCurrentCustomer()
    {
        if (!is_null($this->_currentCustomer)) {
            return $this->_currentCustomer;
        }
        return $this->_getCustomerSession()->getCustomer();
    }

    public function getSettingsHelper()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_settingsHelper)) {
            $this->_settingsHelper = Mage::helper('vendor_module/settings');
        }
        return $this->_settingsHelper;
    }
}

class Vendor_Module_Helper_Settings extends Vendor_Module_Helper_Data
{
    public function someMethod()
    {         
        print_r($this->getCurrentCustomer()->getData());
        exit;
    }
}
```

If I call

```
$helper = Mage::helper('vendor_module');
```

I would expect, as a singleton class, **$helper** would remain the same instance during the rest of the code flow, so...

```
$helper->involveCustomer($customer);
```

Now **$_currentCustomer** has been set, and it contains a customer object

But then, calling

```
$helper = Mage::helper('vendor_module');
$helper->involveCustomer($customer);
$settings = $helper->getSettingsHelper();
$settings->someMethod();
```

The customer object printed is the customer logged in, not the one involved 2 lines before... Am I missing something?

If helpers are called as singleton I bet I should get the right customer object... In fact, I have been assuming this since I started to work with Magento, and now I feel really confused :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that is just not how Class Inheritance works

If you have a `SingletonA` class and extend another Singleton from your class means:

`SingletonB extends SingletonA`

An object `SingletonB` won't share the values which were set in an object of SingletonA.
So to solve this one, you may want to use 'vendor_module' from inside the Vendor_Module_Helper_Settings class, instead the other way around.

```
<?php
class SingletonA
{
  protected $var = 'initial';

  public function set($a)
  {
        $this->var = $a;
  }

  public function get()
  {
    return $this->var;
  }
}

class SingletonB extends SingletonA
{
  public function getVar()
  {
    return $this->get();
  }
}

$singletonA = new SingletonA();
$singletonB = new SingletonB();

$singletonA->set('test');
echo $singletonA->get();
echo '---';
echo $singletonB->getVar();
```

outputs:

```
test---initial
```

---

If you take a look at the `helper` function of the `Mage.php` class of Magento1 you will ensure pretty fast that helper classes **are** Singletons in Magento1.
Like most other object, created by Mage.php, also the helper objects are stored inside the Mage.php registry.

---

Comment: Oh my... Thanks